# Docker mounts /etc/hosts files from host system to container

Tags: docker, volume, hosts

I met with such a problem for myself.
I have a need to limit the disk space inside the container.
At the moment, I started using the "--storage-opt size=4G" option to limit disk space, but when I then execute the "df -h" command in the container, I see that the hosts file is mounted from the host system and has a full amount of disk space that is not equal to the allocated space in the "--storage-opt size=4G" option.

```
root@b74761f5e0bf:/# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay         4.0G   16K  4.0G   1% /
tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm

> /dev/sdb1        16G  447M   16G   3% /etc/hosts

tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /proc/scsi
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/firmware
```

The problem is that when I start writing to the host file, I have the opportunity to fill 100% of the disk space of the host system.

For example:

```
cat /dev/urandom > /etc/hosts
```

Result of the executed command

```
root@b74761f5e0bf:/# cat /dev/urandom > /etc/hosts
cat: write error: No space left on device
root@b74761f5e0bf:/# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay         4.0G   20K  4.0G   1% /
tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm

> /dev/sdb1        16G   16G   84K 100% /etc/hosts

tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /proc/scsi
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/firmware
```

I noticed that when I do not docker

# docker inspect container_name

output:

```
        "ResolvConfPath": "/mnt/docker/containers/b74761f5e0bf334d9e1c77f1423a57272dede65bb5ab37ca81e91c645f3096ff/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/mnt/docker/containers/b74761f5e0bf334d9e1c77f1423a57272dede65bb5ab37ca81e91c645f3096ff/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/mnt/docker/containers/b74761f5e0bf334d9e1c77f1423a57272dede65bb5ab37ca81e91c645f3096ff/hosts",
```

I see fields ResolvConfPath,HostnamePath,HostsPath.

Which are responsible for this mounting.
But I can't find solutions on how to avoid this mounting in the documentation and on similar questions.
*Does anyone know how I can manage this mount to avoid the described problem?*

**An option that I can use quickly, but which does not suit me, is to mount my hosts file from the host system and set it to read-only mode**

System information:

- Docker version 20.10.12, build e91ed57
- Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa)
- Type file system xfs

Comment: Afaik it is not possible to limit mounts/binds in docker. What you could do (if suitable) is to set a quota for the docker user. Then it is limited for docker containers altogether, but in general this is always quite useful for avoiding containers kill the host os on malfunction. Don't have it out of mind but search for quota and `/etc/fstab`

Comment: use `findmnt` instead of `mount` and `df -h`